# Can't initialize Parse server for Back4App. Keep getting <asynchronous suspension>

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, back4app

I'm keep getting asynchronous suspension when trying to connect to parse(Back4App) server. My code is below. I got conflicting packages after adding parse_server_sdk_flutter: 2.1.0 to pubspec.yaml. So I changed the version of those conflicting packages to ANY.  I have been trying everything, please help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart';

void main() async{
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      /// HIVE STARTS
      await Hive.initFlutter(appDocDir.path);
      await Hive.openBox("Name");
      await Hive.openBox("Type");
      await Hive.openBox("Added");
      await Hive.openBox("Notes");
      /// HIVE ENDS

      /// BACK4APP STARTS
    
      final keyApplicationId = 'XRLZJug8U5VghiklDHLDlGMiChkRsSMYg6O34ZRi';
      final keyClientKey = 'd1WBVMdAhbk32V4S4rCc5YfZnuH0DUPTQbWnbtqD';
      final keyParseServerUrl = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
     await Parse().initialize(keyApplicationId, keyParseServerUrl,
          clientKey: keyClientKey, debug: true);
    
      await Parse().initialize(keyApplicationId, keyParseServerUrl,
          clientKey: keyClientKey, autoSendSessionId: true);
    
      /// test
      var firstObject = ParseObject('FirstClass')
        ..set(
            'message', 'Hey ! First message from Flutter. Parse is now connected');
      await firstObject.save();
    
      print('IT IS WORKING');
    
      /// BACK4APP ENDS
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

**Error message is loctaed below:**

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
Restarted application in 1 815ms.
E/flutter ( 6454): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
E/flutter ( 6454): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 6454): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6454): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)




E/flutter ( 6454): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6454): #2      PackageInfo.fromPlatform (package:package_info/package_info.dart:43:9)
E/flutter ( 6454): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6454): #3      Parse.initialize (package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart:68:39)
E/flutter ( 6454): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6454): #4      main (package:trav21/main.dart:64:2)
E/flutter ( 6454): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6454):
```

Dependencies in pubspec is listed below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: any 
  fab_circular_menu: ^1.0.0
  hive: any #^2.0.0
  hive_flutter: any 
  path: ^1.8.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: any
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shimmer: 1.1.2
  reorderables: any
  animator: ^3.0.0
  flutter_animator: ^3.1.0
  http: any # ^0.13.0
  xml2json: ^5.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  parse_server_sdk_flutter: any
```

Comment: Unfortunately Parse Flutter sdk is not working well for Flutter 2.0 yet. A solution is being finalized and you can follow the updates in this thread: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/issues/541. In the meantime, you'd need to either use Flutter 1.22 or not use any other migrated package.

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

RodrigoSMarques on github solved it!

parse_server_sdk_flutter:
git:
url: https://github.com/RodrigoSMarques/Parse-SDK-Flutter.git
ref: nullsafety
path: packages/flutter